# how to set customvalidity on a readonly input field

Tags: javascript, html, readonly, customvalidator

I have discovered that setCustomValidity tooltip is not working on readonly input fields. It actually makes sense because , editable fields are only available for validation.

How can I show alert message customValidation for readonly fields ?

thx

Comment: I don't think you can, and the real question is why would you, what good does it do the user to know that a read-only input is not valid, if they can't change it ?

Comment: U can change it but not manually. For ex, there a menu which opens when readonly field is clicked. And the value field is being set by that menu but there should be selected fields on it. please do not tell me that "then show the error on the menu" because for look&feel, it is not good for UI.

Comment: It’s not good for users to have a UI where widgets act in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. The HTML5 spec clearly [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-readonly-attribute): “If the readonly attribute is specified on an input element, the element is barred from constraint validation.”